# Why the finite sequences space $\mathbb{K}^\infty$ with the final topology is a locally convex topological vector space?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space#Space_of_all_finite_sequences),
it is claimed that the finite sequences space $\mathbb{K}^\infty$ with the final topology is a locally convex topological vector space. But I couldn't figure out how to prove this, both for why it is a topological vector space and why it is locally convex. Can someone help me with this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: According to book <Topological Vector Spaces and Their Applications> example 2.3.3, it appears that the final topology in the category of topological spaces, category of topological vector spaces and category of locally convex topological vector spaces could be different in some cases.

Comment: read a good book on TVS's maybe?

Comment: Far more generally, for every sequence of Banach spaces $X_n\subseteq X_{n+1}$ with compact inclusion operators, the inductive limits in the categories of topological spaces, topological vector spaces, and locally convex spaces coincide. Such spaces are called LS-, or DFS-, or Silva-spaces. This is closely related to the Banach-Dieudonné theorem which you find in books about locally convex spaces, probably, in Jarchow's and certainly in Koethe's book (the latter is not so easy to read).